# Can I create pbr textures from blender and export it to Unreal or Unity?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, export

I would like to experiment with pbr on blender, using the pbr feature, I know people who export from substance painter  as albedo map, normal map, specular ,etc from substance to another engine such as unity or even unreal, I noticed that "whatever happens in cycles dies in cycles", but can my luck change ?
if I create Pbr maps and export in from blender cycles-Pbr to an engine?
pd : Cycles nodes does not exist in another engine! ,but pbr is an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"PBR" is a buzzword that refers to some shader design conventions, such as respecting energy conservation, using fresnel reflections, and such. "PBR Textures" are merely textures intended for some shader that follows these conventions. As Cycles is a render engine itself and not a texture authoring tool, it won't be helpful in authoring textures. You can certainly paint textures using Blender's texture painting function that target a PBR shader, but as Blender doesn't have a PBR viewport shader you will won't have the instant viewport feedback of how your textures are looking. You have to export them out to your game engine, doing some "guess and check" with the values.

Comment: it is like guess and check? it means I should create some texture maps and export it to another software , apply the textures to the slot and check them in real time?

Comment: Yep. Once HP can see what they look like, you can go back and paint more, or adjust them with an image editor such as GIMP or Photoshop. It's not as efficient as working in dedicated texturing tools like Substance, but it gets the job done

Comment: but can I create an albedo, spec map ,normal map ,height map, oclution map in cycles? and then bake every slot of this textures and save it and expor them? I like photoshop or gimp to create every map , but prefer to make them in cycles and search the way to make more realistic a Spainter.

Comment: You could, but it won't be very easy or intuitive, again, you won't have any preview for what you're doing. These textures are just images (and with the exception of normals and occlusion, are usually not baked, btw). You can create them in any tool that creates images, it's just a lot harder without a dedicated tool like Substance. Cycles is a render engine  With the exception of baking, it does not create textures.